Admin deleted a good answer, what and how to fix my Answers to be better and understand going forward
I'm not sure where to post this, if there is a better place please let me know. I recently answered a question that says the question was deleted by an admin and I don't understand why. It may be because it didn't answer the question with code but simply corrected flaws in the self-answer posted, I had to post it as an answer rather than a comment since I don't have enough points to comment. Perhaps it's subjective and the admin didn't find the answer helpful although the op did. Please don't downvote without leaving a comment, I'm asking a question that deserves an answer to why or at very least where this question is better asked. This only minimizes points and adds to the inability to help others.
